# Enable Close button in Win 32 Message Box

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using the [MessageBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx) function provided by the Win 32 framework to display a *Yes and No* message box. I need to keep enabled the close button (the X in the top right corner) but unfortunately seems that is available only when the window contains also a **Cancel** button.

Is it true or there is some other way to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need this? And why can't you also use a Cancel Button? So what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Create your own message box.

Comment: Putting the Cancel button can be confusing for the user (No and Cancel would have the same meaning in this context) so I'd rather to  leave only the two buttons. About why I need this, well let's say that it's just my current task :)

Comment: No and Cancel do not mean the same thing.

Comment: In this case the Message Box is asking to the User if they want to confirm the execution of an operation and No stands for "No, I don't want to continue", that is pretty much the same, I think

Comment: No and cancel are not the same thing. It may be that in this specific instance, answering no to your question has the effect of cancelling the action. But in general, no and cancel definitely do not mean the same thing. Since you actually want to allow the user to cancel this operation, one wonders why you don't just offer that.

Comment: @simoneL: In some cases, `No` and `Cancel` can be handled the same (anything not `Yes` should be treated as `No`).  But in other cases, `No` and `Cancel` should definitely be handled separately (in a loop, keep looping if `Yes` or `No`, just don't perform an action on `No`, and stop the loop on `Cancel`). So it really depends on your particular situation whether you should use `MB_YESNO` or `MB_YESNOCANCEL`.  In your example, `Cancel` does not make sense so you should not enable it.

Comment: No is an answer as valuable as Yes, isn't it?; try this: ("do you want to keep your files?","Formatting c:").  what would be your response? clicking on [ X ] ?

Answer (score 0):

The message box design reflects the platform UX guidelines. In a modal dialog, if you present a close button, the user needs to have a clear expectation of what action that button provokes. And the platform UX guideline is that the close button performs the **cancel** action.

So, that is why the close button is enabled if and only if the dialog presents a cancel button. This design allows the user to be confident that when they press the close button, the action relating to the dialog will be cancelled.

There is no mechanism provided by the API to subvert this UX design in the standard message box. If you are keen to offer your own UX design, that varies from the platform UX standard, then you can create your own dialog and use that. Once you create your own dialog, you are able to enable or disable whatever buttons you please.

However, I urge you not to do this.You intend to present a dialog with a yes/no question and have the close button be used to mean either no. That is counter to the prevailing platform UX and will be confusing to users. If the cancel action is not meaningful, then do not offer a close button since the close button means cancel.

Comment: What you say applies to the `MessageBox...` family of dialogs, but does not apply to the newer `TaskDialog` dialog that replaces `MessageBox` in Vista+.  [`TaskDialogIndirect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760544.aspx) allows you to specify a `TDF_ALLOW_DIALOG_CANCELLATION` flag: "*Indicates that the dialog should be able to be closed using Alt-F4, Escape, **and the title bar's close button** even if no cancel button is specified in either the `dwCommonButtons` or `pButtons` members.*"

Comment: @Remy That would still could as cancel wouldn't it?

Comment: If the `TDF_ALLOW_DIALOG_CANCELLATION` flag is enabled, `IDCANCEL` is returned if the dialog is dismissed via its close button. So yes, closing the dialog is treated as a cancel operation. I'm merely pointing out that your statement that "the close button is enabled if and only if the dialog presents a cancel button" is not true for a TaskDialog as the API allows the close button to be enabled even if there is no cancel button.

Comment: as a user, if i face this situation on a valuable data, i will not click on [ X ] to cancel. i will terminate the process itself from task manager.