# SWT MessageBox close button is disabled

Tags: java, swt, messagebox

I'm using Java SWT for the application UI. When I use SWT `MessageBox` in order to ask the user a question, I use:

```
MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(new Shell(Display.getCurrent()), SWT.YES | SWT.NO | SWT.ICON_QUESTION);
```

But when the dialog is open, the close (red X button) is disabled. What can I do in order to make it enabled?

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://www.coderanch.com/t/331016/GUI/java/Enable-Disable-Window-Close

Comment: @JoeyRoosing That link is about Swing, this question is about SWT.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new Shell there, you should be passing an existing shell.

Comment: @gregh-449 You are right, I failed to notice that the link was about swing. Apologies. I'll continue to look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry for you but this is not possible. From looking into the source code of Java SWT I investigated:
src/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/MessageBox.java Line 206:

```
OS.MessageBox (hwndOwner, buffer1, buffer2, bits);
```

that runs native C code with JNI:
src/os.c Line 8939:

```
rc = (jint)MessageBoxA((HWND)arg0, (LPSTR)lparg1, (LPSTR)lparg2, arg3);
```

So thats the real Win32 API Code for MessageBox that is encapsulated by Java SWT. And there it is not allowed to enable the [X] Button. As your can read here:
[Enable Close button in Win 32 Message Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076909/enable-close-button-in-win-32-message-box)
It is only enabled if you add a SWT.CANCEL button, then the [X] acts the same way.

Comment: thanks! you are right. I switched to using in all the cases messageboxes with ok and cancel only :(